# Completing with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to make a autocompleteer for the input of my webbrowser, for example if you press the tab key, the word `htt` is self-complete to add `tp://` to the value of my input

The autocompletion property must only be valid if the user enters "htt" at the beginning of the URL.

I thought to make the autocompletion validated by a regular expression:

```
 if(event.keyCode == 9){
      if(myInput.value.match(/^(h|ht|htt|http|http:|http:\/)/)){
          myInput.value = "http://";
      }
 }
```

But the result is not the expected one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things to change:

- You are not assigning to `myInput.value` because you have a comparison there with `==` instead of `=`.
- The regular expression should better have an end of string anchor `$` or else other text following the initial "h" (maybe after editing the "http" that was already there) could get replaced -- probably undesirable.
- The default behaviour of the TAB key should better be cancelled so the autocomplete is not only possible when you leave the input box. However, changing the default behaviour of the TAB key would not have my preference.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
myInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9){
        if(this.value.match(/^(h|ht|htt|http|http:|http:\/)$/)){
            this.value = "http://";
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
```

Comment: Good answer overall, however I would suggest a somewhat more scalable pattern: `h(?:t(?:t(?:p(?::\/?)?)?)?)?`

Comment: @CAustin, yes that is indeed more efficient, although I guess regex parsers would (should?) actually be smart enough to compile it that way (except for the non-capturing group, which remains of course a difference).

Comment: Thank you for your answers! That's exactly what I was looking for it's amazing, thank you for your expertise